# Update __proto__ property after updating new reference of an Object

Tags: javascript

```js
class Animal {
  constructor() {
    
  }
}

let animal = new Animal();

// first case
animal['__proto__']['__id'] = 1;
console.log(animal['__proto__']);

// second case
animal = new Animal();
console.log(animal['__proto__']);
```

My question: why doesn't the second clear/remove property `__id` from `__proto__`?

`animal` in the first case and `animal` in the second case reference to same class (Object). But in OOP, when I reset the instance of an object, all properties would be reset, too. It's not for `__proto__` in this case.

So, why?

Comment: `Why should it be cleared?

Comment: `__proto__` is not the animal object, but another, shared by all animal objects. That's the whole idea of the prototype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind prototypes is that all instances created by a given constructor (which means all instances of a given class, if you're using ES6 classes) share a single prototype object.  It's just a single object that exists and can be modified: a new one prototype object isn't made every time a new instance is created, because the point is that it's shared.

These two lines are equivalent; though the second is the preferred way of doing it*.

```
animal["__proto__"].foo = "foo";
Animal.prototype.foo = "foo";
```

If you're trying to set an id, something that should be unique to the instance, then just set it on the object itself, and not on the prototype.

*  `__proto__` was only even standardized as part of the language in ES6; and only then because all the browsers implemented it anyway